# How to initialize child objects when using object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Still learning Typescript and I have this object

```js
export class Marker {
    position: {
        lat: number,
        lng: number,
    };
    label: {
        color: string,
        text: string,
    };
    title: string;
    options: {
        animation: any,
    };
}
```

and in my code where I use it I do so like this, but marker.position is undefined

```js
for (const ybEvent of this.Events) {
  const marker = new Marker();
  marker.title = ybEvent.name;
  marker.position.lat = ybEvent.latitude;
  marker.position.lng = ybEvent.longitude;
  marker.label.color = 'blue';
  marker.label.text = ybEvent.description;
  marker.options.animation = google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE;
  this.markers.push(marker);
}
```

What is the best way to initialize position, label, and options in this object?

Comment: first set `marker.position = {}` and then `marker.position.lat = some value`

Comment: if you want to go deeper than first level you need to initialise it with object, or you can use object literal  `marker.position = { lat : some value , ...}`

Comment: is that the best way to create, initialize and use objects in ts?

Comment: IMO This has nothing to do with ts, it's just how js works. there are certain way to do it, one by manually initialising, object.assign, object literal. choice depends on your preference.

Comment: thanks. should I keep this post or delete it?

Comment: One quick question is Marker class is manually written or it is a third party code ? if manually written and on every instance you need these property you can initialise it there itself. if at some places you need these property and at some places don't then create a wrapper class to add these and use that class

Comment: I created this class 'Marker'. It's a class that is a Google Map marker.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're using a `class`? An `interface` could do the job just fine

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would recommend you to use Typescript on strict mode.

When you use typescript with strict mode, an error will be show if a class member does not have any initialization:

[image]

I would also define the structure of each object (also inside objects).

```
interface Position {
    lat: number,
    lng: number,
}

interface Label {
        color: string,
        text: string,
};
interface Options {
        animation: any,
}
```

And if your Marker object does not require any internal logic, then I would also set it as an interface:

```
interface Marker {
    position: Position;
    label: Label;
    title: string;
    options: Options;
}
```

And your initialization could be something like:

```
for (const ybEvent of this.Events) {
    const position: Position = {
        lat: ybEvent.latitude,
        lng: ybEvent.longitude,
    };

    const label: Label = {
        color: 'blue',
        text: ybEvent.description,
    }

    const options: Options = {
        animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    }

    const marker: Marker = {
        position,
        label,
        options,
    }

    this.markers.push(marker);
}
```

Or without intermediate objects:

```
for (const ybEvent of this.Events) {

    const marker: Marker = {
        position: {
            lat: ybEvent.latitude,
            lng: ybEvent.longitude,
        },
        label: {
            color: 'blue',
            text: ybEvent.description,
        },
        options: {
            animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        }
    }

    this.markers.push(marker);
}
```

Keep in mind, the idea of Typescript is to have `type` safety. If you initialize a object in this way `myObject = {}` it does not have any type information.